# set property attribute dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a object name Person with properties firstName, lastname.

How can I dynamically add attribute on those public properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean attributes, e.g.

```
 [Description("Foo")]
```

then you can't add those at execution time. They're part of the metadata associated with the class. I mean, you could generate the class itself at execution time, but I'm not sure that's really what you want to do.

Could you tell us more about the bigger picture here?

Comment: I using Linq to SQl which generates the classes and relationships. I cannot extend the properties of the classes and I need to add few attributes on each property of the generated class. What would be a good solution to this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393687/how-can-i-add-my-attributes-to-code-generated-linq2sql-classes-properties, which has the answer, and is otherwise an exact duplicate of your question, down to L2S context.

Comment: I would delete this answer (having voted to close) but as it's the only post with the context for the close reason, I'll leave it for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Attributes are meta-data stored in the compiled assembly and it pertains to the Type Person, not to the Object Person that you have.