# ASP.NET - Get DisplayNameFor model outside the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In have a typed view of :

```
@model modelLib.Client
```

But further down the code I want the `DisplayNameFor` of a property for **another** model, precisely the `modelLib.Licence` model.

Normally, for the typed model I would do :

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prop) // Client
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You should use Reflection to get attributes data. Can you say What attribute to you use? `DisplayName` or `Display` abouve your model property?

Comment: Is there any relation between `Client` and `License`?  That is, somewhere in the property hierarchy of the `Client` object is there a `License` object?  If so, you can navigate to that:  `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomeLicense.SomeProperty)`

Comment: @teovankot `modelLib.Licence` has 2 properties `Name` and `End`, each with `[Display(Name = "Something")]`

Comment: @David Yes there is, but it's a collection

Comment: i gess [this is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475513/1849444) you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In response to comments above...)

Just use the property on the nested model.  For a single instance, it would be something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomeLicense.SomeProperty)
```

For a collection of instances, where the parent model has a collection of the nested model, you can refer to an instance in the collection:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomeLicenses.First().SomeProperty)
```

It may *appear* that the call to `First()` could fail in the event that there are zero elements, but it never *actually* invokes `First()` in this case.  The reference itself is just used by the framework for what I might call "some reflection trickery" to get type information so it can reference the attributes on that property.