# Blazor displayname

Tags: blazor, .net-5

I try to find a simple way to get the DisplayName of a model property.

```
DisplayName("FullName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

In an .razor page I can not seems to get it in (example) label or even see it in an InputText

```
<label asp-for="Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>


 <InputText class="form-control" DisplayName="Model.Name" @bind-Value="@Model.Name" />
```

Does anybody knows how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension method:

```cs
public static string GetDisplayName<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
{
    Type type = typeof(TModel);

    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    string propertyName = ((memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo) ? memberExpression.Member.Name : null);

    // First look into attributes on a type and it's parents
    DisplayAttribute attr;
    attr = (DisplayAttribute)type.GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault();

    // Look for [MetadataType] attribute in type hierarchy
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910532/attribute-isdefined-doesnt-see-attributes-applied-with-metadatatype-class
    if (attr == null) {
        MetadataTypeAttribute metadataType = (MetadataTypeAttribute)type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (metadataType != null) {
            var property = metadataType.MetadataClassType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (property != null) {
                attr = (DisplayAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
    return (attr != null) ? attr.Name : String.Empty;
}
```

and call it this way:

```cs
HelperNamespace.GetDisplayName(YourClass, m => m.Name)
```

and if you want to use this in Blazor, you can do it this way:

```cs
<label class="control-label">@(HelperNamespace.GetDisplayName(YourClass, m => m.Name))</label>
```

Comment: Thank you Umair. But it delivers me an null result.
The type is filled with the model. type = {Name = "Scope" FullName = "MyServer.Models.Scope"}. Property is been good (type and name)
but after that nothing is been working with it.(attr = null), after that metadataType = null and then he returns string.empty