# How to add property-level Attribute to map ColumnAttribute at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, reflection, attributes, datamapper

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143650/how-to-add-property-level-attribute-to-the-typedescriptor-at-runtime/) we have implemented the ColumnAttribute association with the corresponding property, but when Linq to SQL tries to map this property to a Column it doesn't work.

Our property and mapping code(from the other question):

```
    public System.Xml.Linq.XElement Name {
        get {
            return this.name;
        }
        set {
            this.OnNameChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this.name = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Name");
            this.OnNameChanged();
        }
    }

        System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute columnAttribute = new System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute();
        columnAttribute.Name = "Name";
        columnAttribute.Storage = "name";
        columnAttribute.DbType = "Xml NOT NULL";
        columnAttribute.CanBeNull = false;
        columnAttribute.UpdateCheck = System.Data.Linq.Mapping.UpdateCheck.Never;

        PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptor propertyOverrideTypeDescriptor = new PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(ClassToMap)).GetTypeDescriptor(typeof(ClassToMap)));
        PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(ClassToMap)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray().Where(prop => prop.Name == "Name").FirstOrDefault();

        PropertyDescriptor pd2 = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(
            typeof(ClassToMap).GetType(),
            pd, // base property descriptor to which we want to add attributes
            // The PropertyDescriptor which we'll get will just wrap that
            // base one returning attributes we need.
            columnAttribute
            // this method really can take as many attributes as you like, not just one
        );

        propertyOverrideTypeDescriptor.OverrideProperty(pd2);
        TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new TypeDescriptorOverridingProvider(typeof(ClassToMap)), typeof(ClassToMap));
```

Any idea how to refresh the table mapping?

Comment: I've tried this other alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393687/how-can-i-add-my-attributes-to-code-generated-linq2sql-classes-properties but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection does not utilize type descriptors. Your test probably passed because another attribute is added to a class in code.

There is a way to change LINQ to SQL classes mapping on the fly. The trick is to add a XML mapping file to resources and use it when you create a data context. When you load XML data into memory, you can modify mappings as your needs dictate. This solution was described in detail here: [Linq to sql using dynamic tables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5e0af64-0057-4498-998b-70db656a0e9f/linq-to-sql-using-dynamic-tables)

The code snippet:

```
foreach (XElement col in xe.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Column")) {
    XAttribute name = col.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Name" && a.Value == "CategoryName");
    if (name != null)
        name.Value = "Name";
}
```

Comment: The example shows how to change the name of a database or a table. I need to add a ColumnAttribute. I don't see how to do it with xml mapping. Any idea?

Comment: That example demonstrates a general approach. If you look at the XML file, you will see that column properties are defined this way:       <Column Name="CategoryID" Member="CategoryID" Storage="_CategoryID" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" AutoSync="OnInsert" />
Where a mapping to a database field is defined via the Name attribute.

Comment: I've added Name attribute and still not working. My property's name is Name. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Is your code similar to mine? I have recently added it to the answer.

Comment: Is there any other method to obtain the xml besides SQLMetal?
Is there any other way to do the mapping without the xml with the same DataContext instance?